When does derived tensor product commute with arbitrary products?
Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. It is well-known that $M$ is finitely generated if and only if the functor $M\otimes_R (-)$ preserves arbitrary products (for instance, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053569/when-does-the-tensor-product-distribute-over-an-infinite-direct-product
.)
I want to ask now a similar question for the derived category: Let $X$ be an object in the derived category $D(R)$ of all $R$-modules. Is it true that $X\otimes_R^{\mathbf L}(-)$  preserves arbitrary products if and only if $X$ is a perfect complex? If not, is there any other interpretation for  $X\otimes_R^{\mathbf L}(-)$ to preserve  arbitrary products?

This is true with no noetherian hypotheses.
Indeed, this condition implies that $X\otimes^L_R -$ commutes with all homotopy limits: it commutes with finite homotopy limits always (it commutes with finite homotopy colimits, and $D(R)$ is stable so this implies also commuting with finite limits); and if a functor commutes with products and finite limits, it commutes with all limits (build sequential limits out of an equalizer of products, and $\Delta$-indexed limits out of sequential limits and finite limits).
It follows that the map $X \otimes_R^L R\hom_R(-,R) \to R\hom_R(-, X)$ is an equivalence on all of $D(R)$ (it is an equivalence at $R$, and the condition implies that the collection of objects on which it is an equivalence is closed under homotopy colimits), in particular at $X$.
Now it is well-known that if the identity of $X$ lifts to $X \otimes^L_R R\hom_R(X,R)$, then $X$ is perfect : from the general theory of symmetric monoidal categories, it implies that $X$ is dualizable, and since the unit $R\in D(R)$ is compact, it implies that $X$ is compact, and $D(R)^\omega= Perf(R)$ is one of the definitions of $Perf(R)$ (though one can again prove that it is equivalent to any of the other ones: dualizability, or being in the thick subcategory generated by $R$, or being represented by a finite complex of finitely generated projectives)

At the end, did you mean the identity of $\operatorname{RHom}_R(X, X)$ ? Could you please elaborate the last part? Thanks :)

@uno It is saying that $\operatorname{id}_X$ lies in the image of ($H_0$ of) the evaluation $\operatorname{RHom}_R(X,R)\otimes_R^LX\to\operatorname{RHom}_R(X,X)$. This is equivalent to the dualizability of $X$, and for $D(R)$, it is equivalent to perfectness.

This might be very stupid, but why my hypothesis implies commuting with homotopy limit? And , Thank you @Z.M for the explanation

i have added details about both points
